# Why use a singleton to wrap broadcast variables?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I saw an example code in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount.java

The code uses singleton to wrap broadcast variables like this:

```
class JavaWordBlacklist {

private static volatile Broadcast<List<String>> instance = null;

public static Broadcast<List<String>> getInstance(JavaSparkContext jsc) {
  if (instance == null) {
    synchronized (JavaWordBlacklist.class) {
      if (instance == null) {
        List<String> wordBlacklist = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        instance = jsc.broadcast(wordBlacklist);
      }
    }
  }
  return instance;
}
}
```

And initials the broadcast variable in `wordCounts.foreachRDD((rdd, time) -> {...}`

My question is that why not just declare `private static volatile Broadcast<List<String>> instance = null;` in parent class, i.e., `JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount`?

(In my opinion, since the broadcast variable is initialed in `foreachRDD()` that is executed in single driver thread, no race condition will occurred here, so singleton protection is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to address problems emerging from checkpoint recovery. Remember that checkpoints capture only metadata and or distributed state, not broadcast variables, accumulators, and local objects. After application is restarted from checkpoint, all state has to be recovered manually.

No to address your point:

> since the broadcast variable is initialed in foreachRDD() that is executed in single driver thread,

Driver is not single threaded, and broadcast variables are accessed for different purposes than data processing (book keeping, reporting) There can be also accessed by multiple streams at the same time.